# Error in typing the paragraph in the "Snippet"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm beginner Dev. I'm developing a code using ejs but when editing the paragraph in the "snippet" it's giving an error. I broke the paragraph to not be too long but it gave an error when doing that.

Someone help me please!

```
app.set('view engine','ejs')

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    const blogs =[
        {
            title: 'Thomas Sankara (Burkina Faso)',

            snippet: 'Earlier this month a court in Burkina Faso's capital
                     indicted former President Blaise Compaoré for his role
                     in the murder of his comrade, Thomas Sankara on 15 October 1987.',

            author: 'Jocelyne Botshimbo M pusa',
            createdAt: Date.now(),
        }
    ]
    res.render('index',{blogs: blogs})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a backtick `` ` ``, it is called Template String and it supports multiline.

```js
const blogs = [
    {
        title: 'Thomas Sankara (Burkina Faso)',
        snippet: `Earlier this month a court in Burkina Faso's capital
                 indicted former President Blaise Compaoré for his role
                 in the murder of his comrade, Thomas Sankara on 15 October 1987.`,

            author: 'Jocelyne Botshimbo M pusa',
            createdAt: Date.now(),
    }
]
```